# maximum server memory setting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, memory

Just had a memory issue on a 64GB of RAM machine with SQL Server 2012 SP2. 3 running db engine instances, each limited to 16GB (16384). But noticed in Task manager that sqlservr.exe was at over 30GB memory for one of them.

What is the cause ? And is there any way to see what's eating up the RAM, next time it happens ? 
Can anyone explain if there's any way to limit the memory used by one instance, besides the "Maximum server memory" setting ?

Comment: First, @Shanky just posted a good writeup on [not using Task Manager](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96087/45616) to monitor memory in SQL Server. You may see more memory used in 2012 since it has [different memory configurations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2663912) than previous versions - short version being you cannot explicitly limit all of the RAM it may consume.

Comment: Thank you, good read. Not using -g. x64 all the way, no AWE here. However, the issue was real, even if Task Manager might be wrong, memory was overused by that instance, as SSRS's logs showed a lot of reports were failing due to "System.OutOfMemoryException".